# Reinstall Windows on Ubuntu?

Tags: windows-8, reinstalling

I've been wondering this for years now and I've been a proud Ubuntu user since 2010, I *don't* want to switch back to windows and I've even deleted the OS form my PC, but would it be possible to reinstall Windows if it was deleted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably...

*Depending on your hardware*, more modern versions of Windows might not run any more, but if you free up all space on the *first internal hard drive on the first primary partition* installing Windows again *should* be possible.

Why 1st HD, 1st partition?  Microsoft has a near-monopoly and can *dictate* how and when Microsoft products need to be installed... ;-)

Before you try this out, however, read [this Q&A](https://askubuntu.com/questions/569679/whats-a-good-back-up-strategy-for-1-desktop-pc) first!  You've now been promoted to user type 4!!!

Comment: As you're a reputation 1 user: If this all works, don't forget to click the grey check-mark under the "0" at the left of this text, which means "yes, this answer is valid"!  ;-)

Comment: I haven't been on SE for a while and just got back i figure it out thanks again for the awnser